# Dúvida Multithreading em C#

Tags: c#, thread, multithreading

Tenho o seguinte cenário:  Podem ser criados três tipos de threads no programa, imagine que sejam, A, B e C. Tenho que respeitar a seguinte regra:

Uma thread **C não** pode acessar a região crítica se já houver **uma ou mais** threads **B** em execução e **vice-versa**. (Threads A podem executar independente de quantas ou quais outras também estão executando)

Minha pergunta é: Qual a maneira mais eficiente de implementá-la em C#?

Comment: O que você quer dizer com **região crítica**? Está se referindo à uma variável compartilhada?

Comment: Qual e' a diferenca entre threads A e B? Pela descricao, parece-me que ambas podem executar a regiao critica sem restricoes.

Comment: O problema é uma adaptação do Problema do Banheiro Unissex feita pelo meu professor. Suponha que as threads do tipo C sejam homens e B mulheres. Elas podem sim executar a região crítica, mas nunca ao mesmo tempo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando disparar a Thread C faça a verificação se a Thread B está em execução utilizando a propriedade:

```
Thread.IsAlive
```

Caso false realiza os procedimentos da Thread C.